# trying to create two local variables on the stack but can only create one

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to create two local variables on the stack that are counters
for two loops, but I'm only able to create one. Do I need to push the variables that I can't 
create one on the stack as local variables, or am I going about it all wrong? Here's the code I have so far:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 100h

printf proto c arg1:ptr byte, printlist:vararg

.data

array dword 180,8,9,10,40,80,0
fmtmsg2 db 0dh,0ah,0
fmtmsg1 db "%d ",0
counter dword 6,0
.code

bubbleSort proc
  push ebp
  mov ebp,esp
  sub esp,4
  mov dword ptr[ebp - 4],0
  mov esi,[ebp + 12]
  mov ebx,[ebp + 8]

  ;trying to create two local variables but only can create one
  mov edx,0
  ;mov ecx,0


innerloop:
        inc dword ptr[ebp - 4]       ;========>   ;inc ecx           
        cmp dword ptr[ebp - 4],ebx   ;=========> ;cmp ecx,ebx         
      je outerloop       
      mov eax,[esi]      
      cmp eax,[esi + 4]  
      Jge noexchange 
        ;exchange values   
      xchg eax,[esi+4]   
      mov [esi],eax      
  noexchange:
      add esi,4           
      jmp innerloop          

outerloop:
     mov esi,offset array

     ;inner loop counter
     mov dword ptr[ebp - 4],0           ;========>;mov ecx,0 

     ;outer loop counter
     inc edx     

     cmp edx,ebx
     jne innerloop

     ;loop 3 counter
     mov edx,0

     ;load array offset
     mov esi,[ebp + 12]

     mov esp,ebp
     pop ebp
     ret 8
bubbleSort endp

displayArray proc
     push ebp
     mov ebp,esp
     mov esi,[ebp + 12]
     mov ebx,[ebp + 8]
     mov edx,0

     loop3:
     mov eax,[esi]
     push edx
     invoke printf,addr fmtmsg1,eax
     pop edx

     add esi,4
     inc edx
     cmp edx,ebx
     jne loop3

     invoke printf,addr fmtmsg2

     pop ebp
     ret 8
displayArray endp

public main

main proc

      push offset array
      push counter
      call bubbleSort

      push offset array
      push counter
      call displayArray

     ret
main endp

end main
```

When I try to add another local variable the program crashes and I dont know what the problem is.

Comment: A bit unclear. You want to change your *current* code (which uses `[ebp-4]`, the only local stack based variable in your code) to use `ecx`, or the other way around? Are you confusing register variables with stack variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the stack grows downwards - hence parameters passed on the stack are positive (relative to the stack pointer or its copy in ebp), local variables (stored in a "hole" which you insert) are negative and the return address (usually unused by the code) is at 0.

```
sub     esp, 4          ; allocates 4 (extra) bytes on the stack.
    ....
mov dword ptr[ebp - 4],0   ; References those 4 bytes
    ....
mov esp,ebp                ; Puts the stack pointer back where it was
```

To allocate 2 variables of 4 bytes, you need to allocate 8 bytes from the stack and refer to them as -4 and -8 relative to ebp.

Comment: nvm its ok i tried adding mov dword [ebp - 8] and allocating two local on the stack but only one works not both ill just figure it out my self thanks

Comment: Did you remember to change the initial allocation to sub esp, 8?